# Angular5 node js and npm installation problems

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have the latest versions of Node and NPM installed, using which I installed Angular/cli, but it's shooting me with following errors: **angular/cli and npm versions not compatible with current version of node**.

I suspect that I may(not) be installing out of the proper directory. But at this point, what else can I do? thanks.

Please check: [Screenshot with details of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYtmi.png)

Comment: I think the error log is pretty clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the reqs.
Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.

You are using the latest node.js 9.2 
you need to uninstall or rollback to 8.9 !!

Here is a guide
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Hope this solves it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar problem, but the solution was quite simple : my path was too long.
I shortened it a bit (two directories down) and then I did the install again with success.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with angular/cli version not compatible with the current node version.  This generally happens when you are upgrading from lower version of Angular to any other higher version.
You can try following steps:

```
npm outdated  --> To list latest and current package details in local application.
npm update    --> to update the local packages.
```

If it still doesn`t work, 
Try deleting the 'node_modules' folder and install dependencies of fresh:

```
npm install
```

You can then check whether all packages, including the cli is not outdated.

Comment: Also you might need to update your package.json. This can be done by executing following command 'ncu -u'

Comment: Alright, so I want to update on your suggestion, Rahul. I checked the list of outdated versus the updated versions. Then, I 'npm update' the cli, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Oh great... Happy Coding... 